# Is this structure of the code is correct?

Tags: html, css

I'm starting with html and css and I'm a little lost with structure of code.
I mainly concerned about  tags, should I use inside of them  and the same question to  and other new elements from html5.

Here is code which I want to use for website:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  color: #67BE7A;
  width: 1150px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

header {
  color: #0EA632;
  width: inherit;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: orange;
}


/* nav {
    width:inherit;
    height:60px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color: pink;
    
    }
    */

#baner {
  width: inherit;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: brown;
}

section#main {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #0EA632;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 340px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #0B8328;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
}

section#contact {
  width: inherit;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #5E5E5E;
}

nav {
  width: inherit;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0px solid #0d962d;
  background-color: #0ea632;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 2px -6px #888888;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0ea632, #075c1b);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to      6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#0ea632, #075c1b);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0  */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0ea632, #075c1b);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#0ea632, #075c1b);
  /* Standard syntax */
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

nav li+li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  /*float:left saving this */
  content: url('../img/separator.png');
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/*height is equal to height of nav - padding top and bottom*/

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 21px 10px 21px 10px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 21px 10px 21px 10px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #1ee84e;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style2.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="content">
    <header></header>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Element 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="baner"></div>
    <section id="main"></section>

    <aside></aside>

    <section id="contact"></section>

  </div>



  <footer></footer>



</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The title says it. :D

Comment: Is it right? Have you tested it; does it *work?*

Comment: I would suggest you use an HTML IDE. Try Aptana studio

Comment: It's works great without any problems, but the question is if this isn't just wrote wrong but with good effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO it's not!

While skimming through I noticed several problems.

I noticed you have css linked via a link element

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style2.css"/>
```

Which is good, but after your closing html tag you have css down there. Don't do that!

Also it's bad practice to have an element with nothing inside it, which you did with 3 elements.

> ```
> <header></header>  
> <aside></aside>  
> <footer></footer>
> ```

Values of 0 shouldn't have units specified. So this...

```
margin:0px;
```

should be...

```
margin:0;
```

I assume you're new to coding, or at least new to this language. I suggest starting off using a [coding playground](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) that has syntax validation build in to start off with. My project [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/) would be a good one to start off with. There's also [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) which is like Github for web designers and developers.

Comment: I have css code in another file. There is link element to this file: <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style2.css"/> . I also know about that these elements shouldn't be empty. But I was just testing structure so I didn't need anything inside.

Comment: Thanks for answer about units. And this missing </html> is my mistake with post so sorry about that.